# modifying "else" in a ternary statement, and/or spacing an array of mixed objects when printing

Tags: ruby, arrays, ternary-operator, justify

I have a program that plays bingo. It creates a random bingo board, and continuously makes random balls, and if the ball matches a number and column on the board, replaces it with an "X". My replace method looks like this:

```
  def replace
    i=0
    while i < @balls.length
      @bingo_board_in_columns[@balls[i][0]].map! 
          { |num| (num == @balls[i][1]) ? "X" : num }
      i+=1
    end
    @bingo_board = @bingo_board_in_columns.transpose
  end
```

@balls is an array of the randomly selected balls. You'll notice the ternary statement, which says to just leave "num" alone if it doesn't match a ball. I'd like to change the num, which is an integer, to a string.

```
@bingo_board_in_columns[@balls[i][0]].map! 
    { |num| (num == @balls[i][1]) ? "X" : num.to_s }
```

Trying num.to_s seems to create an infinite loop however, or else it just takes a reallllly long time. That alone I do not understand.

The reason why I want to do this, is so that at the end of my program when I call

```
p ["B", "I", "N", "G", "O"]
@bingo_board.each {|e| p e}
```

it will print a nice little square that looks like a bingo board. In order to print my nice square, I need to justify the items inside my @bingo_board array, but unfortunately Fixnums can't be justified. So my idea was to just change them to strings and justify accordingly.
What it looks like:

```
["B", "I", "N", "G", "O"]
[ 34, "X", "X", 17, 89 ]
[ "X", "X", 89, "X", "X" ]
[ "X", "X", "X", 9, 36 ]
[ "X", "X", 28, "X", "X" ]
[ 54, "X", "X", 49, "X" ]
```

What I want it to look like (notice the vertical bingo under "I"):

```
["B", "I", "N", "G", "O"]
[ 34, "X", "X",  17, 89 ]
["X", "X",  89, "X", "X"]
["X", "X", "X",  9 ,  36]
["X", "X",  28, "X", "X"]
[ 54, "X", "X",  49, "X"]
```

or something to that effect

To sum up:

- why doesn't my "else" clause in the ternary statement like changing
  "num" to a string? (or doing anything else to it for that matter)
- is there a better way to print my bingo board in a nice little
  square? In other words spacing the elements inside the sub arrays?

**EDIT** clarify @bingo_board and @balls

```
  def initialize
    @bingo_board = Array.new(5) {Array(5.times.map{rand(1..100)
      })}
    @bingo_board_to_columns = @bingo_board.transpose
    @bingo_hash = [["B", 0], ["I", 1], ["N", 2], ["G", 3], ["O", 4]].to_h
    @balls = Array.new()
  end


  def random_ball
    @balls = @balls << [@bingo_hash.values.sample, rand(1..100)]
    return @balls
  end
```

Comment: @muistooshort Clarified with an edit

Answer (score 1):

No clue what's up with the `to_s`.  Are you absolutely sure that's where the time is being spent?  We don't have all the code to see what's in those arrays for real, so it's hard to say.

As for the printing, you can't just dump arrays into `p` or `puts` and hope to have control over it, you need to format the text. Try something like this:

```
board = [["B", "I", "N", "G", "O"],
         [ 34, "X", "X",  17, 89 ],
         ["X", "X",  89, "X", "X"],
         ["X", "X", "X",  9 ,  36],
         ["X", "X",  28, "X", "X"],
         [ 54, "X", "X",  49, "X"]]

board.each do |row|
  puts "%2s %2s %2s %2s %2s" % row
end
```

Which puts out:

```
 B  I  N  G  O
34  X  X 17 89
 X  X 89  X  X
 X  X  X  9 36
 X  X 28  X  X
54  X  X 49  X
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. I also clarified what's going on under the hood a little bit with an edit, perhaps that will illuminate the problem with num.to_s @nickveys